# Arrange Items in Listview at Runtime

Tags: listview, vb6

I have a form that contains a listview, textbox, and add button. When i click the add button, the text that i type in the textbox will display to the listview

I want to rearrange/order by alphabet  or numeric after i click the add button ( in runtime and without clicking the column header  ).

Here's my Code:

```
Private Sub Add_Click ()

   Listview.listitems.add(1).text = text1.text
   Listview.listitems.item(1).subitems(1) = text2.text

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

   With Listview.columnheaders
      .Add, , "Column 1"
      .Add, , "Column 2"
   End with

End sub
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: The ListView control has a `Sorted` property, set it to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListView control has a `Sorted` property, you should set it to `True`. You can do that using the designer or using code. In that case, your `Form_Load` code should be something like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With ListView.ColumnHeaders
        .Add , , "Column 1"
        .Add , , "Column 2"
    End With

    ' This will sort by the first column
    ListView.SortKey = 0
    ' Sort in an ascending order
    ListView.SortOrder = lvwAscending
    ListView.Sorted = True
End Sub
```

Also, note that you don't need to specify the index when adding an item since the list is sorted. Also please note that the way you add the items now will *always* change the sub-item of the *first item*. If you need to change the sub-item of the recently added item (i.e., add items in both columns at the same row), you'd need to change that to look something like this:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
    Dim newItem As ListItem
    Set newItem = ListView.ListItems.Add()
    newItem.Text = Text1.Text
    newItem.SubItems(1) = Text2.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You. It helps a lot. 

Comment: Thank You so much. If you have time, please answer my new question.